# Como eu faço para capturar apenas os últimos 2 dígitos do ano corrente?

Tags: c#

Como eu faço para capturar apenas os últimos 2 dígitos do ano na função `DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()`?

Preciso fazer uma validação, por exemplo, se o ano é 2019, preciso que compare só o 19, não vou postar o código, pois é só o `DateTime.Now.Year` mesmo que eu preciso trabalhar e não estou conseguindo, o resto do código indeferi dessa parte

Comment: Não seria isso: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");`?

Comment: Também achei que seria, mas não funcionou, me retorna uma string vazia

Comment: Se retorna uma string vazia provavelmente o formato e/ou tipo recebido de "data" esta errado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1º forma**

Sabendo que o ano é composto por 4 caracteres, podemos utilizar o método `Substring()` para pegar todo o conteúdo a partir do segundo caracter de nossa string:

```
// 2019 - Iremos pegar a partir do índice 1 todo o conteúdo para frente
string ultimosDigitosAno = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2);
```

**2º forma**

O método `ToString()` para o tipo `DateTime` aceita como parâmetro o formato de data que queremos utilizar, no entanto, podemos passar o formato `yy` que significa que queremos apenas o ano no formato de 2 dígitos:

```
// 2019 - Formatação para retornar apenas 2 dígitos
string ultimosDigitosAno = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");
```

Answer (score 3):

Olá Poderia tentar isso

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 30); 
string onlyTwo = date.ToString("yy");
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar: [String.Substring Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2)
```

Funcionando em ***[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KH8eUo)***

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: @JonathanIgorBockornyPereira por nada e bem vindo ao stackOverflow, recomendo dá uma leitura rápida no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre como funciona as coisas por aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas formas, depende muito do que deseja e principalmente como a informação da "data" esta chegando (tipo/formato).

**Exemplos:**

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy"));

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Year - (DateTime.Now.Year / 100 * 100));

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Year % 100);
```